# Adding client id or class attribute for each th in the DataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, tomahawk

I 've tried a lot of ways to put a client id or css class in `<th>` tags, but i haven't succeeded what i did. In fact, i want to specify class or id for each `<th>`. Normally there is **columnHeader** property for  but when i want to use it i am getting a `"Attribute headerClass invalid for tag column according to TLD"` error. `<datatable headerClass>` only allows a general description (for all `<th>`). When I use `<h:outputText styleClass>`, it writes into `<span>` . Is there another way to ensure this?

```
<t:dataTable 
    cellpadding="0" 
    cellspacing="0"
    id="dtGrade"
    value="#{gradeBean.scoreRows}"
    var="scoreRow"
    rowIndexVar="scoreRowIndex"
    sortColumn="#{gradeBean.sortColumn}"
    sortAscending="#{gradeBean.sortAscending}"
    columnClasses="left,left,left,left,left"
    styleClass="dtgrade">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <t:commandSortHeader 
                    columnName="studentSortName" 
                    propertyName="studentSortName" 
                    arrow="true" 
                    immediate="false" 
                    actionListener="#{gradeBean.sort}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msgs.Fullname}"/>
                </t:commandSortHeader>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{scoreRow.Student.sortName}"/>
        </h:column>
        ...
</t:dataTable>
```

Comment: `t:datatable` is from? Tapestry?

Comment: Sorry, could you give a little more detail? No, it is not Tapestry.

Comment: How  can **_I_** give you more detail on what **_YOU_** use?

Comment: It's Tomahawk. At least, I don't recognize any other component library which has a "commandSortHeader". Apparently OP is working on a jurassic JSF 1.x based beast.